# JQuery Animation: Animate DIV left to right at different speed than top to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

trying to animate 1 DIV at a certain speed left to right (and back), and also animate it top to bottom (and back) at a different speed (essentially creating a windows-like screensaver effect).

problem is that each animation occurs after each other (obviously) but i'm hung up on trying to combine so that the image will animate diagonally.

coming from CSS animation this is easy, but with that it can't detect responsive window width/height so bounce edges get real wonky.

any ideas? big thanks.

code so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    updateWindowsize();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        updateWindowsize();
    });
    bounceBounce();

});

var imageWidth = '540'
    imageHeight = '705'

function updateWindowsize() {
    var $window = $(window);
    windowHeight = $window.height();
    windowWidth = $window.width();
}

function bounceBounce() {

    $('.div-1').animate({"left": windowWidth - imageWidth}, 3000, 'linear',
          function(){ $(this).animate({left: 0}, 3000, 'linear');
    });

    $('.div-1').animate({"top": windowHeight - imageHeight}, 6000, 'linear',
          function(){ $(this).animate({top: 0}, 6000, 'linear');
    });

    bounceBounce();

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
$('.div-1').animate({"left": windowWidth - imageWidth, "top": windowHeight - imageHeight}, 6000, 'linear',
      function(){ $(this).animate({left: 0, top: 0}, 6000, 'linear');
});
```